# How to count elements of an href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some Javascript that parses out the name of a site so that I can query an XML file to pull data where the node's attribute is the last part of a URL.

```
<script> 
  function myExampleSite() 
  {
    var myURL = window.location.href;
    var dashIndex = myURL.lastIndexOf("-");
    var dotIndex = myURL.lastIndexOf(".");
    var result = myURL.substring(dashIndex + 1, dotIndex);
    return result;
  }

  var exampleSite = myExampleSite();
</script>
```

For example, if the site is `http://myexamplesite.com/status-Blah00` I would be able to get all data out of the `Blah00` XML node and populate various aspects of the site with whatever is in the XML.

This works fine and I am able to use the URL name (Status-Blah00, Status-Blah01, etc.) to query XML against it and populate elements on the page based on the name of the site.

However I ran into problems where a site has a second `-` in the URL.
For example:

```
http://myexamplesite.com/status-Blah01-Blah00.htm
```

It should be parsing the `Blah01-Blah00` node of my XML, but instead of just gets the data from `Blah00` since it doesn't recognize the first `-`.  I'm new to javascript and I'm confused as to how to basically do:

```
if 1 "-" in url then get last index 
else the number of "-" in url is > 1, get first index.
```

How would I be able to count the number of "-" in the URL and logically do just that with the above Javascript?

Comment: If there's 1 "-", aren't the first index and the last index the same thing? Why not just get the first index all the time?

Comment: Use regex with (.com/)(.+).htm

Comment: Using regex for something like this would make it easier I feel

Comment: The first example produces `".com/status-"` instead of `"Blah00"`.

Comment: Good point Barmar... Your idea solved this for me, if you want to post that as an answer I'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex for this problem. Here is a start:

```
"status-Blah01-Blah00.htm".match(/([^-]+)/g)
```

That code generates the array:

```
["status", "Blah01", "Blah00.htm"]
```

So you can work with the length of that array to find out how many hyphens are in the url.

Even easier: `"status-Blah01-Blah00.htm".split('-')` returns the same array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single line with sequential regexes that can handle dashes occurring elsewhere in the url and that keeps the Blah01-Blah00 node as a single string rather than separating them, as it seems you requested.

```
"http://www.site-name.com/folder-name/01-10-20/status-Blah0100-Blah01.htm".match(/-([^.\/]+)\.htm/g)[0].match(/[A-z0-9][A-z0-9\-]+/g)[0]
```

Generates:

```
"Blah0100-Blah01"
```